# "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication" from the SH script

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, x11

I have very unusual error while executing a GUI programs (using X11) from the ssh server.
Firstly I login with xeyes on my Mac OX

```
ssh -X user@server xeyes
```

than I run any of the GUI x11 program and everything is OK!

but when I try to run the same program from the sh script it does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
HOME=/home/gleb/amber_mds
prog=vmd


for sim in ${HOME}/md_* ; do
  pushd ${sim}
  ${prog} -input somefile
  pwd
  popd
 fi
done
```

The error which I do have

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

I have checked .Xauthority and /etc/ssh/sshd_config and everything is OK!
Also the display cariable set correct.

```
gleb@T-bioinfo:~/amber_mds$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Could someone help me to resolve an issue?

Thanks!

Gleb

Comment: Means exactly what it says. `.Xauthority`-the-file isn't the only thing involved; the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable's value matters too.

Comment: btw, unrelated to your problem, but you're much better off `for sim in "$HOME/md_"*; do (cd "$sim" && exec vmd -input somefile); done`. Right now you've got a bunch of potential bugs that can happen if a `pushd`/`cd` operation fails, if a home directory name contains spaces, etc. And scoping the `cd` to the subshell that invokes your program means it's guaranteed not to impact anything else (whereas using `exec` ensures compensates for the cost of that subshell by not doing another `fork()` call before invoking `vmd`).

Comment: How to set up these variable correctly? I try to call it and obtain empty line :-) BTW I edited my script how you have said, but it resulted in the same error :-(

Comment: Yes, the suggested edits are for different errors, not the one you're seeing now (hence, "unrelated to your problem").

Comment: `declare -p XAUTHORITY XAUTHORIZATION DISPLAY` would provide a more complete dump than `echo` does. I don't expect all three to be set, but even the little details like the flags in the output (such as the distinction between `--` and `-x`) are important.

Comment: btw, consider `ssh -Y` rather than `ssh -X`.

Comment: By the way -- a "sh script" is a script using `#!/bin/sh` as its shebang. Since you use `#!/bin/bash`, what you have is a bash script, not a sh script.

Comment: gleb@T-bioinfo:~$ declare -p XAUTHORITY XAUTHORIZATION DISPLAY
-bash: declare: XAUTHORITY: not found
-bash: declare: XAUTHORIZATION: not found
declare -x DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"

Comment: ssh -Y   gives the same error